# Proof by Induction Divisibility.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

$6^n-5n+4$ is divisible by 5 for all positive integers $n$.
$n >=1$

Prove By Induction
My attempt is as follows:

> $n=1$
>   $6^1-5(1) +4$
>   $=5$, Therefore 5 is divisible by 5 so $n=1$ is true
>   
>   Assume its true for $n=k$
>   consider $n=k+1$
>   $6^k-5k+4=5.x$
>
> I am stuck here would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $6\equiv 1\mod 5$.

Prove $6^n\equiv 1 \mod 5$

The term in $5n$ is a distraction.

Comment: I'm not sure, if it's helpful with induction proof.

Comment: You can prove that $6^n\equiv 1 \mod 5$ by induction. You don't need induction to prove that $5|5n$.

Comment: Oh, you've right. It's possible to do it like here. As I look at it now, I think, more elegant will be proof $$6^n + 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{5} \Longrightarrow \left(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\right) \left(6^n+4 = 5k\right) \Leftrightarrow 6^n-5n+4 = 5(k-n)$$
However, It isn't the most obvious way. +1 because it's interesting, but I don't think proving it by induction like that has sense.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $6^n+5n+4$ is a multiple of $5$, so
$$
6^n+5n+4=5x
$$
for some integer $x$.
Now you want to do the inductive step; since $6^{n+1}$ seems to be the toughest term, we isolate $6^n$ from the previous identity:
$$
6^n=5x-5n-4
$$
and recall that $6^{n+1}=6\cdot6^n$; then
\begin{align}
6^{n+1}+5(n+1)+4
&=6\cdot6^n+5(n+1)+4\\
&=6(5x-5n-4)+5(n+1)+4\\
&=5(6x-6n+n+1)-24+4\\
&=5(6x-5n+1-4)\\
&=5(6x-5n-3)
\end{align}
is a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $6^n+5n+4$ is multiple of $5$.

Let us consider $$6^{n+1}-5(n+1)+4=(5+1)6^n-5n-5+4=5(6^n-1)+(6^n-5n+4)$$

The first summand is multiple of $5$  and the second is multiple of $5$ by inductive assumtion.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem, $6^n=(1+5)^n=1+5n+5^2a$, and so $6^n-5n+4=5+5^2a$.

Comment: Induction appears in the binomial theorem...

Answer (score 1):

prove that $6^n-5n+4$ is divisible by 5.

### 1) Prove true for n=1

$6^1-5(1)+4= 5$, which is divisible by 5. Hence, the preposition is true for n=1.

### 2) Assume true for n=k, given true for n=1.

$6^k-5(k)+4= 5a$, where a is some integer.

### 3) Prove true for n=k+1, assuming true for n=k.

$6^k+1 -5(k+1)+4 =5b$, where b is some integer.

$=6^k.6^1 -5k-5+4$, ($x^a+b$ can be written as $X^a.x^b$ , where $6^1=6$.)

$=6.6^k-5k+4-5$ (some simple rearranging)

=6.5a -5  (from assumption that $6^k-5k+4=5a$)

=5(a+6-1) -factorising by taking 5 out common.

### = 5(a+5) ---> if multiplied by 5, it must be then divisible by 5.

Therefore the preposition is true for n=k+1, assuming true for n=k and proven true for n=1. This completes the proof.